# How to populate a dropdown with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to populate a dropdown (AJAX) when I click on the dropdown.
I have a dropdown categories and a button Add categories

When I open the page the first time, I can see my categories inside the dropdown.
If I want to include another categories, I click on Add categories and I insert my new categories.
After, if I click on the dropdown, I must see my new categories.

How to do that ?

I don't know exactly how to create that.

Thank you

my_ajax_file.php

```
 $Qcheck = $OSCOM_Db->prepare('select categories_id as id,
                                      categories_name as name
                               from :table_categories');
 $Qcheck->execute();
 $list = $Qcheck->rowCount();
 if ($list > 0) {
   $array = [];
   while ($value =  $Qcheck->fetch() ) {
     $array[] = $value;
   }

   # JSON-encode the response
   $json_response = json_encode($array); //Return the JSON Array

   # Return the response
   echo $json_response;
```

**HTML code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function Mycategory_id() {
     $("#myAjax").on('click', function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: 'http://www.my_ajax_file.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
           //data returned from php
         }
       });
     });
   }
 </script>

 <select name="category_id" id="Mycategory_id" class="form-control">
   <option value="0" selected="selected">Haut</option>
   <option value="23">Panneaux Signalétique</option>
   <option value="20">Signalétique Camping</option>
   <option value="22">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Barrières</option>
   <option value="21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entrée</option>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" name="current_category_id" value="0" /></div>
```

Comment: Do you want to insert new Category into DB also? if so then you need another insert ajax api.

Comment: no,because the add button make that. Just when you click on the dropdown, il must display the categories informations

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the select element with new options.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Mycategory_id() {
    $("#myAjax").on('click', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.my_ajax_file.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          //data returned from php
          var options_html = '';
          for(index in data){
            var category_id = data[index]['categories_id'];
            var category_name = data[index]['categories_name'];
            options_html += '<option value="'+category_id+'">' + category_name + '</option>';

          }
          $('#category_id').html(options_html);
        }
      });
    )};
</script>
```

To make rendering easy, you can use mustache.js

Comment: $('#category_id').html(options_html); This line will do that. It will select the select element by id 'category_id'  and populate the html. 
Another method is to append new option element one by one. Please see jquery append, for that.